# C# filename + filepath to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a function that will open a file dialog, but it won't return me the filepath + filename.

What am i missing?

```
private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browseDatabase(accessDatabaseTextbox.Text, "mdb bestanden|*.mdb");
    }

    private void browsebutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browseDatabase(klantenDatabaseTextbox.Text, "accdb bestanden|*.accdb");
    }

private void browseDatabase(string textbox, string filter)
    {
        openFileDialogDB.Filter = filter;

        if (openFileDialogDB.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string DBfile = openFileDialogDB.FileName;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(DBfile))
            {
                textbox = DBfile;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selected file doesn't exist.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No file selected.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by '*but it won't return me the filepath + filename*'? Have you tried debugging the line that assigns the file name to DBFile to see what value it contains?

Comment: When debugging it shows that DBFile had this line C:\\Users\\myuser\\Downloads\\Test.mdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need the selected file end up in your `accessDatabaseTextbox`.  In this case you are doing it wrong, string is being passed by value. Try this

```
private void browsebutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    klantenDatabaseTextbox.Text=browseDatabase( "accdb bestanden|*.accdb");
}

private string browseDatabase(string filter)
{
    openFileDialogDB.Filter = filter;

    if (openFileDialogDB.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string DBfile = openFileDialogDB.FileName;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(DBfile))
        {
            return DBfile;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected file doesn't exist.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No file selected.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
 return "";
}
```

Comment: It gives me the following error, Error 6 The out parameter 'textbox' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method and A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter

Comment: You are welcome. Seems like reading this might help you in the future http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx